# Check if NSURL is a directory

Tags: swift, nsurl

While using Swift I want to check if an `NSURL` location is a directory. With Objective-C this is not a problem and working find, but when I convert the code to Swift I run into a runtime error.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

```
import Foundation

let defaultManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
let localDocumentURLs = defaultManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsDirectory,
includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsPackageDescendants, error: nil) as NSURL[]

for url in localDocumentURLs {
    var isError: NSError? = nil
    var isDirectory: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<AnyObject?> = nil
    var success: Bool = url.getResourceValue(isDirectory, forKey: NSURLIsDirectoryKey, error: &isError)
}
```

Comment: where does the runtime error happen exactly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

that is working quote well on my side:

```
var error: NSError?
let documentURL : NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true, error: &error)
var isDirectory: ObjCBool = ObjCBool(0)
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(documentURL.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
    println(isDirectory)
}
```

*NOTE: it checks whether the* `Documents` *folder is a folder. you can replace the URL with anything, of course.*

Comment: thx, this approach is working - I've made some small modifications, because    NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) returns allows true in my case ? isDirectory actually holds the real information. Many thx for your help.

Comment: yes, `fileExistsAtPath()` returns whether the path does exist, the `isDirectory` will hold the info whether or not the path is a folder.

Comment: Man... I was doing `var isDir:ObjCBool = false` instead of `var isDir:ObjCBool = ObjCBool(0)` now I understand that `false` and `true` are auto-bridged to NSNumber not ObjCBool.

Answer (score 36):

In iOS 9.0+ and  macOS 10.11+ there is a property in `NSURL` / `URL`

**Swift:**

```
var hasDirectoryPath: Bool { get }
```

**Objective-C:**

```
@property(readonly) BOOL hasDirectoryPath;
```

However this is only reliable for URLs created with the `FileManager` API which ensures that the string path of a dictionary ends with a slash.

For URLs created with custom literal string paths reading the resource value `isDirectory` is preferable

**Swift:**

```
let isDirectory = (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]))?.isDirectory ?? false
```

**Objective-C:**

```
NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
[url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:nil];
NSLog(@"%i", isDirectory.boolValue);
```

Comment: really a shame that this answer appears somewhere in the middle only.

Comment: @ThomasKilian  The question has been asked and answered in 2014, iOS 9 was released about a year later 

Comment: Well, it's THE answer today. So often I get struck here with the right answer being somewhere in between and not on top.

Comment: This property doesn't look at the file system to find out if the URL actually points to a directory: `URL(string: "file:///var/")!.hasDirectoryPath` is `true` (note the trailing `/`), while `URL(string: "file:///var")!.hasDirectoryPath` is `false`. Checking the `resourceValues` is the better approach.

Comment: The real answer no doubt

Answer (score 17):

Swift 3

```
extension URL {
    var isDirectory: Bool {
        let values = try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey])
        return values?.isDirectory ?? false
    }
}
```

Comment: The perfect way to find out for sure!

Answer (score 4):

Plenty of answers here... but they all have one thing in common:
 
They all use `FileManager` (which is in fact `NSFileManger`).

This approach has one downside: **`FileManager` is not thread-safe!** Using a `FileManager` from different threads in parallel usually works for stateless operations, but that is nowhere guaranteed (you might be building on undefined behavior when you rely that this works).

A safe implementation would have to create a new `FileManager` instance every time, yet that would be horrible performance, or use one per thread, which is huge management overhead.

There's a much better, much simpler approach I'd like to present here, that doesn't need any 3rd party class:

```
extension URL {
    var isDirectory: Bool? {
        do {
            let values = try self.resourceValues(
                forKeys:Set([URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey])
            )
            return values.isDirectory
        } catch  { return nil }
    }
}
```

That's it. Using the `resourceValues()` method you can also easily query other interesting information, like the size of a file or the last modification date. This is a very powerful API, that exists for ages for `NSURL` in Obj-C as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the swift 2.0 version of the original poster's code:

```
        do {
            var rsrc: AnyObject?
            try element.getResourceValue(&rsrc, forKey: NSURLIsDirectoryKey)
            if let isDirectory = rsrc as? NSNumber {
                if isDirectory == true {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        } catch {
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

my 2 cents ...
swift NSURL way: (based on holex's answer)

```
var error: NSError?

// since getting it as URLForDirectory, it flags it as dir, for custom path: NSURL:fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:
let documentURL:NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true, error: &error)

// passes true, if it exists and validates as dir (as flagged in the NSURL object)
if (documentURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error) {
    println(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

... and this is a Swift 3 extension on `FileManager`:

```
extension FileManager {
    func isDirectory(url:URL) -> Bool? {
        var isDir: ObjCBool = ObjCBool(false)
        if fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory: &isDir) {
            return isDir.boolValue
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```